# subprocess readline hangs waiting for EOF

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, pipe, readline

I have a simple c++ program that I'm trying to execute through a python script.  (I'm very new to writing scripts) and I'm having trouble reading output through the pipe.  From what I've seen, it seems like readline() won't work without EOF, but I want to be able to read in the middle of the program and have the script respond to whats being outputted.  Instead of reading output, it just hangs
the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
def call_random_number():
    print "Running the random guesser"
    rng = subprocess.Popen("./randomNumber", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    i = 50
    rng.stdin.write("%d\n" % i)
    output = rng.stdout.readline()
    output = rng.stdout.readline()

call_random_number()
```

and the c++ file, which generates a random number between one and 100, then checks the users guess until they guess correctly

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

int main(){
  std::cout<< "This program generates a random number from 1 to 100 and asks the user to enter guesses until they succuessfully guess the number.  It then tells the user how many guesses it took them\n";
  std::srand(std::time(NULL));
  int num = std::rand() % 100;
  int guessCount = 0;
  int guess = -1;
  std::cout << "Please enter a number:  ";
  std::cin >> guess;
  while(guess != num){
    if (guess > num){
        std::cout << "That guess is too high.  Please guess again:  ";
    } else {
        std::cout << "That guess is too low.  Please guess again:  ";
    }
    std::cin >> guess;
    guessCount++;
  }
  std::cout << "Congratulations!  You solved it in " << guessCount << " guesses!\n";
}
```

the eventual goal is to have the script solve the problem with a binary search, but for now I just want to be able to read a line without it being the end of the file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@Ron Reiter pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7897356/4279),  you can't use `readline()` because `cout` doesn't print newlines implicitly -- you either need `std::endl` or `"\n"` here.

For an interactive use, when you can't change the child program, [`pexpect` module](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) provides several convenience methods (and in general [it solves for free: input/output directly from/to terminal (outside of stdin/stdout) and block-buffering issues](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

if sys.version_info[:1] < (3,):
    from pexpect import spawn, EOF # $ pip install pexpect
else:
    from pexpect import spawnu as spawn, EOF # Python 3

child = spawn("./randomNumber") # run command
child.delaybeforesend = 0 
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout # print child output to stdout for debugging
child.expect("enter a number: ") # read the first prompt
lo, hi = 0, 100
while lo <= hi:
    mid = (lo + hi) // 2
    child.sendline(str(mid)) # send number
    index = child.expect([": ", EOF]) # read prompt
    if index == 0: # got prompt
        prompt = child.before
        if "too high" in prompt:
            hi = mid - 1 # guess > num
        elif "too low" in prompt:
            lo = mid + 1 # guess < num
    elif index == 1: # EOF
        assert "Congratulations" in child.before
        child.close()
        break
else:
    print('not found')
    child.terminate()
sys.exit(-child.signalstatus if child.signalstatus else child.exitstatus)
```

It works but it is a binary search therefore [(traditionally) there could be bugs](http://www.solipsys.co.uk/new/BinarySearchReconsidered.html).

Here's a similar code that uses `subprocess` module for comparison:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen("./randomNumber", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,
          bufsize=1, # line-buffering
          universal_newlines=True) # enable text mode
p.stdout.readline() # discard welcome message: "This program gener...

readchar = lambda: p.stdout.read(1)
def read_until(char):
    buf = []
    for c in iter(readchar, char):
        if not c: # EOF
            break
        buf.append(c)
    else: # no EOF
        buf.append(char)
    return ''.join(buf).strip()

prompt = read_until(':') # read 1st prompt
lo, hi = 0, 100
while lo <= hi:
    mid = (lo + hi) // 2
    print(prompt, mid)
    print(mid, file=p.stdin) # send number
    prompt = read_until(':') # read prompt
    if "Congratulations" in prompt:
        print(prompt)
        print(mid)
        break # found
    elif "too high" in prompt:
        hi = mid - 1 # guess > num
    elif "too low" in prompt:
        lo = mid + 1 # guess < num
else:
    print('not found')
    p.kill()
for pipe in [p.stdin, p.stdout]:
    try:
        pipe.close()
    except OSError:
        pass
sys.exit(p.wait())
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure adding newlines in your C++ program will cause the readlines to return.

Comment: yeah, but I want to be able to make scripts for existing programs, rather than modify programs to fit the scripts

Comment: There is no generic way to "solve" EOF issues. Otherwise, how would you know the line has actually ended? If you know the program, don't read until a newline, just read the exact amount of characters you need. Otherwise, make it return a newline. Your other alternative is to use timeouts, which is really bad.

Comment: you don't need to read the exact amount. [It is enough if you are nearly in sync](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23795689/4279) (OS pipe buffer provides tolerance).

Answer (score 0):

You may have to explicitly close`stdin`, so the child process will stop hanging, which I think is what is happening with your code -- this can be verified by running top on a terminal and checking if `randomnumber`'s status stays sleeping and if it is using 0% CPU after the expected time it would take to execute.

In short, if you add `rng.stdin.close()` right after the `rng=subprocess(...)` call, it may resume with no problem. Another option would be to do `output=rng.communicate(stdin="%d\n" % i)`and look at `output[0]`and`output[1]`who are `stdout` and `stderr`, respectively. You can find info on`communicate` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate).

Comment: Wow I forgot this question existed.  If you close stdin then you can't communicate with the process anymore, which is what's needed in this case, responding to the output dynamically

Comment: Exactly. I think you should perhaps add an update to the answer so other readers will understand the real cause of the hanging, which is most likely the reason why they ever arrive here. Also, I wouldn't mind if you upped my answer :)

Comment: @RyanHaining: your C++ code does not check EOF on stdin therefore calling `rng.stdin.close()` prematurely leads to an infinite loop in your case. I would use `pexpect` or its Windows analog in this case.

Comment: @RyanHaining +1 for citing `pexpect`, which is totally new to me and could be to other readers. Would you mind elaborating on how it would help with the given issue?

Comment: @LordHenryWotton I don't think you meant to tag me on that, but JF Sebastian has posted a full answer elaborating

Comment: @RyanHaining Thanks, indeed I didn't, and just realized his answer above elaborates on `pexpect`. Sorry about that. Newbie here :)