# Python subprocess.stdout.readline() hang

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I try simple code using subprocess on python, while calling process.stdout.readline() it will hang on it. How to solve this problem? While trying fcntl for nonblock in the output I got blank output.

my source code:

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE 
import fcntl
import os

proc = Popen(['./test'],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE) 

fcntl.fcntl(proc.stdout.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)

print "Started!"

print proc.stdout.readline()

proc.stdin.write('5\n')
proc.stdin.flush()

print proc.stdout.readline()

proc.stdin.write('5\n')
proc.stdin.flush()


print proc.stdout.readline()
proc.stdout.close()
proc.stdin.close()
```

The output should be like this:

```
First number: 5
Second number: 5
Answer: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output suggests that there is no newline after `First number:` and therefore the blocking `proc.stdout.readline()` call (before `proc.stdin.write('5\n')` line) hangs and non-blocking variant returns nothing (empty bytestring) -- there is no newline/EOF to return yet.

To fix it, you could stop reading at the end of the prompt (at the colon `':'`). See [subprocess readline hangs waiting for EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7897202/4279)

Even if there were a newline after the prompt; `readline()` may hang due to buffering issues. See [Python C program subprocess hangs at "for line in iter"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279)

For example, if `test` is equivalent to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
a = int(input('First number: '))
b = int(input('Second number: '))
print('Answer:', a + b)
```

then to get the answer, you could use [`pexpect` module](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect # $ pip install pexpect

def print_result(locals):
    result = int(locals['child'].after.rpartition(b' ')[2])
    print(result)

pexpect.run('./test', events={'First number': '5\n', 'Second number': '5\n',
                              r'Answer:\s*\d+': print_result})
```

If you want to see both input and output; you could set `logfile=sys.stdout` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I meet a similar issue; and fix it by adding flush() before readline.

```
               proc.stdout.flush()
               proc.stdout.readline()
```

Now, I can see the output right away; looks flush() put EOF there; then readline is ready to go.