# python subprocess.stdout.readline doesn't

Tags: python, linux

I have a piece of python code that calls a binary via the `subprocess` module. This binary reads data from `stdin` and outputs other data to `stdout`, which should then be collected by the python code.

Here's how I use this binary in a shell:

```
$ ./check # start reading from stdin here
param_card_orig.dat
0.123809
42.821 0 0 42.821 
91.2246 0 0 -91.2246 
14.5521 -12.9194 -0.441262 6.68258 
33.8782 -4.04952 5.37574 -33.2029 
35.3909 22.0683 2.04142 27.5923 
50.2244 -5.09935 -6.9759 -49.4755
```

with a return after each line (including the last), from which I get the output

```
1.53852538054399053E-004
```

which is again terminated by a newline. However, trying to put this in python code like this:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("./check", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write("param_card_orig.dat\n")
p.stdin.write("0.123809\n")
p.stdin.write("42.821 0 0 42.821 \n")
p.stdin.write("91.2246 0 0 -91.2246 \n")
p.stdin.write("14.5521 -12.9194 -0.441262 6.68258 \n")
p.stdin.write("33.8782 -4.04952 5.37574 -33.2029 \n")
p.stdin.write("35.3909 22.0683 2.04142 27.5923 \n")
p.stdin.write("50.2244 -5.09935 -6.9759 -49.4755 \n")

print("now waiting for input")

print(p.stdout.readline())
```

I receive exactly this:

```
now waiting for input
```

The program is hanging, obviously waiting for some sort of communication to happen. This is partially intended - the `check` binary is supposed to stay active and wait for further input, returning the output of the calculation as soon as a further complete input is supplied - but since the first input is complete, I should have received the result of the calculation, which I obviously didn't, or else we would have seen the printout. When I  break the execution manually with `CTRL+C`, it tells me

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
File "testpipe.py", line 15, in <module>
print(p.stdout.readline())
```

What's going on here? Is this a problem with the way I handle the pipes? Is this a problem with a missing `EOF` or missing newline?

PS: I found this issue [Python subprocess.stdout.readline() hang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276788/python-subprocess-stdout-readline-hang), which is possibly the same, but didn't receive an answer.

PPS: In case it matters, the python version is Python 2.6.6.

Comment: `for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,"")` if you want the output in real time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `p.stdout.read()` instead of `readline()`? It works for the following test code where `invoker.py` creates a pipe with `invoked.py`.

**`invoked.py`**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

# Print a Hello notice
sys.stdout.write("I have been invoked!\n")

# Read the value coming from the pipe
value = sys.stdin.readline()

# Return a "processed" value
sys.stdout.write("New: " + value)
```

**`invoker.py`**

```
import subprocess

# Start pipe with other file
p = subprocess.Popen("./invoked.py", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

# Send a value to the other file
p.stdin.write("Value!\n")

# Print the result coming from the other file
print(p.stdout.read())
```

Comment: Did you run this code? Which python version, which OS?

Comment: This example doesn't run. 

1. If you are running with the shell you should specify with shell=True param in Popen(), else first param should be ["python3", "invoked.py"]


2. p.stdin.write("Value!\n")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'



My biggest problem is when I fix all this the program still hangs at:
print(p.stdout.read())

Comment: Wow! It has been a long time! I just tried running this on a Mac (OSX 10.15) using Python 2.7.17 and it works. Steps I followed: 1. Set the correct path to python on the invoker.py file (In my case `#!/usr/local/bin/python`). 2. Add executable permission to invoker.py using `chmod +x invoker.py`. 3. Run `./invoker.py`.

Comment: Just checked and it worked with Python 3.7.5. Not sure why it is not working for you :( Just to check: You should run `invoker.py` and it will invoke the other file on its own.

Comment: And since this bubbled up due to an edit:  it works w/ Python 2.7.17 in Ubuntu 18.04, it fails /w 3.6.9 ... `File "./invoker.py", line 8, in <module>
    p.stdin.write("Value!\n")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`