# How can i take the output of one python script as user input for another python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-10

i have written a code (python 2.7) that goes to a website [Cricket score](http://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scorecard/16822/ind-vs-nz-1st-test-new-zealand-tour-of-india-2016) and then takes out some data out of it to display just its score .It also periodically repeats and keeps running because the scores keep changing.
i have also written a code for taking a message input from user and send that message as an sms to my number .

i want to club these two so that the scores printed on my screen serve as the message input for sending live scores to me.

codes are

**sms.py**

```
    import urllib2
    import cookielib
    from getpass import getpass
    import sys
    import os
    from stat import *
    import sched, time
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    from urllib2 import Request
    #from livematch import function

    #this sends the desired input message to my number


    number = raw_input('enter number you want to message:  ')
    message = raw_input('enter text: ' ) 


    #this declares my credentials
    if __name__ == "__main__":    
        username = "9876543210"
        passwd = "abcdefghij"

        message = "+".join(message.split(' '))

     #logging into the sms site
        url ='http://site24.way2sms.com/Login1.action?'
        data = 'username='+username+'&password='+passwd+'&Submit=Sign+in'

     #For cookies

        cj= cookielib.CookieJar()
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

     #Adding header details
        opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120')]
        try:
            usock =opener.open(url, data)
       except IOError:
            print "error"
            #return()

        jession_id =str(cj).split('~')[1].split(' ')[0]
        send_sms_url = 'http://site24.way2sms.com/smstoss.action?'
        send_sms_data = 'ssaction=ss&Token='+jession_id+'&mobile='+number+'&message='+message+'&msgLen=136'
        opener.addheaders=[('Referer', 'http://site25.way2sms.com/sendSMS?Token='+jession_id)]
        try:
            sms_sent_page = opener.open(send_sms_url,send_sms_data)
        except IOError:
            print "error"
            #return()

        print "success" 
        #return ()
```

**livematch.py**

```
    import sched, time
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    from urllib2 import Request

    url=raw_input('enter the desired score card url here :  ')
    req=Request(url)
    def do_something(sc) : 
        #global x
        r=requests.get(url)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
        for i in soup.find_all("div",{"id":"innings_1"}):
          x=i.text.find('Batsman')
          in_1=i.text
          print(in_1[0:x])
        for i in soup.find_all("div",{"id":"innings_2"}):
          x=i.text.find('Batsman')
          in_1=i.text
          print(in_1[0:x])
        for i in soup.find_all("div",{"id":"innings_3"}):
          x=i.text.find('Batsman')
          in_1=i.text
          print(in_1[0:x])
        for i in soup.find_all("div",{"id":"innings_4"}):
          x=i.text.find('Batsman')
          in_1=i.text
          print(in_1[0:x])
        # do your stuff
            #do what ever 
        s.enter(5, 1, do_something, (sc,))

    s.enter(5, 1, do_something, (s,))
    s.run()
```

note that instead of using 9876543210 as username and abcdefghij as password use the credentials of actual account.

sign up at way2sms.com for those credentials

Comment: Hi, modify the first program to write to a file instead and the second program to read from that file.

Comment: Please post the code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a completly independed python script in via your python script take a look at `subprocess` module. You could use `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.Popen`.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer without having a look at your code. But it seems that using piping with subprocess would be an appropriate solution.

See the answer on this post: [python subprocess.stdout.readline doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32812157/python-subprocess-stdout-readline-doesnt/32812754#32812754)