# input command doesn't seem to work when used with popen python

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess

I am writing a small python application which executes scala commands. A user can insert the command through the STDIN and then the python app forwards them to the scala interpreter. Once the command is executed, the app shows the result of the operation.

The idea is to use `Popen` to create a pipe by which I can send commands and read results. The idea is quite simple, but it doesn't work.  What I don't understand is, why the `sys.stdin` doesn't work anymore after the pipe is opened. This makes impossible to read commands in python.

This is the code I am using:

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(["scala"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, bufsize=0, universal_newlines=True) as scala:
    while True:
        print("Enter scala command >>> ", end="")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        command = input()
        scala.stdin.write(command)
        scala.stdin.flush()
        print(scala.stdout.readline())
```

Comment: Does your script work if you hard-code `command` instead of reading it with `input`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes it does. I hard-code "4+5" as command and the interpreter returns the correct result.

Comment: `scala` could be buffering its output.

Comment: Since you are doing a "write" and not a "writeline" is the problem that a line terminator is not being sent to scala so it never executes the command?

Comment: @RobertB that's not the problem because that line is not even executed

Comment: What output so you see?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I can see the output of the interpreter, but I can type anything. Therefore the application is stuck at `command = input()`

Comment: @GiuseppePes, it does actually work, you have to add a newline but also get to the `scala>` line first.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham can you add the code please? what version of python are you using?

Comment: @GiuseppePes If nothing else works, you can always try the [pexpect](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) module. It was designed for the use case you're describing.

Comment: @GiuseppePes, I will add it in a sec, just getting the output to line up

Comment: here's a [`pexpect` code example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7897202/4279) (note: you don't need `unbuffer` or `script -q /dev/null` if you use `pexpect`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read all the lines from when the scala starts then input the command with a new line and get the two lines of output after:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(["scala"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, bufsize=0, universal_newlines=True) as scala:
    for line in scala.stdout:
        print(line)
        if not line.strip():
            break
    while True:
        command = input("Enter scala command >>> \n")
        scala.stdin.write(command+"\n")
        scala.stdin.flush()
        for line in scala.stdout:
            if not line.strip():
                break
            print(line)
```

An example run:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_60).

Type in expressions to have them evaluated.

Type :help for more information.



Enter scala command >>> 3+4
scala> 3+4

res0: Int = 7

Enter scala command >>> 4 * 4
scala> 4 * 4

res1: Int = 16

Enter scala command >>> 16 / 4
scala> 16 / 4

res2: Int = 4
```

To get  it to work from bash running it with [unbuffer](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/unbuffer1.html) seems to sort out the output issues:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(["unbuffer", "-p","scala"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, bufsize=0, universal_newlines=True) as scala:
    for line in scala.stdout:
        print(line)
        if not line.strip():
            break
    while True:
        command = input("Enter scala command >>> ")
        scala.stdin.write(command+"\n")
        scala.stdout.flush()
        for line in scala.stdout:
            if not line.strip():
                break
            print(line)
```

If you are using Mac Os x, you should probably use :

```
with Popen(["script", "-q", "/dev/null", "scala"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, bufsize=0, universal_newlines=True) as scala:
```

From bash:

```
        print(line)
## -- End pasted text --
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_60).

Type in expressions to have them evaluated.

Type :help for more information.



Enter scala command >>> 4 + 2
scala> 4 + 2

res0: Int = 6

Enter scala command >>> 4 * 12
scala> 4 * 12

res1: Int = 48

Enter scala command >>> 100 // 25
scala> 100 // 25

res2: Int = 100

Enter scala command >>>
```

More info regarding shell buffer issues:

- http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: I don't know why I am having the same issue even with your code. What operating system are you using? I am using a Mac OSX. I'm trying it now on Linux.

Comment: @GiuseppePes, yes I am using ubuntu.  So the last thing you see is `"Enter scala command >>> "`?

Comment: Exactly. And then nothing changes

Comment: Interesting.. I can't see when I type but then I click enter and it prints what I typed and the result.

Comment: So at least it is not hanging,  where are you running the code from?

Comment: I am running in a ubuntu vm.

Comment: Ah ok, I have the same issue using a bash shell, I was running the code from the  pycharm.

Comment: Yes it seems there is some buffering happening somewhere, I am trying to get a work around

Comment: @GiuseppePes, does `["unbuffer", "-p","scala"]` work for you?

Comment: This works as expected in Linux! :) Thank you very much

Comment: I managed to make it work with Mac os x, and I updated your answer. Thank you very much for your help. I wish I had more +1 ;)

Comment: Great, so it was a buffering issue with osx too? Thanks for the edit, probably a bit better than the man page ;)

Comment: Yes, it was the same buffering issue. `unbuffer` doesn't exist for Mac OSx

Comment: I added in the answer. Can't you see it? it is just after `unbuffer`. Nevertheless, I used `script -q /dev/null/ scala`

Comment: Ah sorry yes,  I just saw the links originally. Might be time to turn the comp off!