# python subprocess multiple stdin.write and stdout.read

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipe, subprocess

Thanks for taking time to answer the question. I am playing around with Python 3.4 and I have two simple python programs. One, a program called test.py that takes a user input and prints something.

```
while True:
    print("enter something...")
    x = input()
    print(x)
    time.sleep(1)
```

To send input to this program, I have another program that uses subprocess:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cat = Popen('python test.py', shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
cat.stdin.write("hello, world!\n")
cat.stdin.flush()
print(cat.stdout.readline())

cat.stdin.write("and another line\n")
cat.stdin.flush()
print(cat.stdout.readline())
```

However when I run the above program, I get an error:

```
enter something...

hello, world!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    x = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

And if I replace test.py with a standard linux command like 'cat', things work as expected.

Is there any way I send multiple stdin writes and read multiple stdout back?

Comment: I think you missed the command **python** on Popen `Popen(['python',  'test.py'], shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)`

Comment: Typo, the program actually runs if you see that the first print works.

Comment: `cat.stdin.write("hello, world!\n")` should raise an error if you use Python 3 (`universal_newlines=True` is required to enable the text mode) therefore either your actual code is different or you are not using Python 3.

Comment: unrelated: you should [`import` the module and call its functions (use `multiprocessing` if necessary) instead of running it as a subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30165768/4279)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you should [use `pexpect` for interactive programs (dialog-based interactions)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/subprocess/info).

Your specific issue might be caused by a python version mismatch (you think your code is executed using Python 3 while actually it might be executed using Python 2). The second issue (`EOFError`) is expected: either catch it in the child script or provide a signal for the child to exit (I use an empty line for that in the code example below).

Here's a Python 3 code that fails loudly on Python 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen([sys.executable, '-u', 'test.py'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,
           universal_newlines=True, bufsize=1) as cat:
    for input_string in ["hello, world!", "and another line", ""]:
        print(input_string, file=cat.stdin, flush=True)
        print(cat.stdout.readline(), end='')
```

Note:

- `sys.exectable` is the current python executable (Python 3 in this case)
- `universal_newlines=True` enables the text mode (otherwise, `cat.stdin` and `cat.stdout` work with bytes, not strings)
- `-u` makes the child's output line-buffered ([otherwise, you won't see anything until the child flushes its internal stdout buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279))
- the `with`-statement closes the pipes and waits for the child process to exit.

And here's the corresponding `test.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time

while True:
    x = input("enter something...")
    if not x: # exit if the input is empty
        break
    print(x)
    time.sleep(1)
```

#### Output

```
enter something...hello, world!
enter something...and another line
enter something...
```

Note: there is no new line after `"enter something..."`

It works but it is fragile, read [Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe) and [use `pexpect` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23795689/4279).

---

If the input is finite and it doesn't depend on the output then you could pass it all at once:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from subprocess import check_output

output = check_output([sys.executable, 'test.py'],
                      input="\n".join(["hello, world!", "and another line"]),
                      universal_newlines=True)
print(output, end='')
```

This version requires that the child handles EOF properly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time

while True:
    try:
        x = input("enter something...")
    except EOFError:
        break # no more input

    print(x)
    time.sleep(1)
```

The output is the same (as shown above).

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation Sebastian! :). How do I read multiple lines? using cat.stdout.readline() will hang forever?

Comment: @waka-waka-waka: both code examples already read multiple lines

Comment: thanks, my question was more on the lines of, I am not sure how many lines to read, when do I break? The test program may print 1 or more lines...

Comment: `check_output()` -based solution reads all output, no matter how many lines a subprocess produces.

Comment: to make it more clear, assume the case where the child does not print anything to the screen, in which case the .readline() will hang forever?

Comment: `check_output()` won't hang even if the child prints nothing.

Comment: thank you, I am almost there... in my case the process has launched previously and i am using psutils and other modules to manage the process. In this case, I am using the popen object to do stdin, stdout etc. cant use check_output since the process is launched in a different context altogether

Comment: @waka-waka-waka: working with a process that you have not started is a different issue.  Ask a separate question.