# Real time read from subprocess.stdout on Windows

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, output-buffering, io-buffering

To emphasize, the problem is **real time read** instead of **non-blocking read**. It has been asked before, e.g. [subprocess.Popen.stdout - reading stdout in real-time (again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140189/subprocess-popen-stdout-reading-stdout-in-real-time-again?rq=1). But no satisfactory solution has been proposed.

As an example, the following code tries to simulate the python shell.

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['python'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = input('>>> ')
    p.stdin.write(line.encode())
    print('>>> ', p.stdout.read().decode())
```

However, it would be blocked when reading from `p.stdout`. After searching around, I found the following two possible soutions.

1. [using `fctrl` and `O_NONBLOCK`](http://eyalarubas.com/python-subproc-nonblock.html)
2. [using `thread` and `queue`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896288/1535111)

Whereas the 1st soution may work and only work on linux, the 2nd soution just turn blocking read to non-blocking read, i.e. I cannot get real time output of the subprocess. For example, if I input '`print("hello")`', I will get nothing from `p.stdout` using 2nd solution.

Perhaps, someone would suggest `p.communite`. Unfortunately, it is not suitable in this case, since it would close stdin as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28616322/1535111).

So, is there any solutions for **Windows**?

**Edited:** Even if `-u` is turned on and `p.stdout.read` is replaced with `p.stdout.readline`, the problem still exists.

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-u'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = input('>>> ')
    p.stdin.write(line.encode())
    p.stdin.flush()
    print('>>> ', p.stdout.readline().decode())
```

**Solution:** The following is the final code based on J.F. Sebastian's answer and comments.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

with Popen(
        ['python', '-i', '-q'],
        stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
        bufsize=0
    ) as process:
    while True:
        line = input('>>> ')
        if not line:
            break
        process.stdin.write((line+'\n').encode())
        print(process.stdout.readline().decode(), end='')
```

It should be noted that the program would hang when the command triggers no output.

Comment: "when reading from stdout" what?  You can't read from stdout.

Comment: the first sentence in the answer to [the question you've linked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3140189/4279) describes the problem: "Trying to write to and read from pipes to a sub-process is tricky **because of the default _buffering_ going on in both directions.**" I have no idea how to force a child process to disable its internal stdout buffering in the general case on Windows—it is easy for `python` executable; just pass `-u` option and perhaps, `-i` to enable interactive mode (if you need to run some other command then read its docs).

Comment: unrelated: `p.stdout.read()` reads until EOF i.e., it is likely won't return until the child process is dead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian It seems so. Curiously, with `-u` and `p.stdout.readline()`, it doesn't work neither.

Comment: @cqdjyy01234 unless you are running a script; `-u` is not enough. To enable interactive mode, pass `-i` option, as I said above. Also, call `p.stdin.flush()` (to empty stdin buffer in the parent).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I think there exists misunderstandings. As edited, `-u` is passed to the subprocess to disable internal buffer, and `readline` is used to avoid the EOF problem. Moreover, `p.stdin.flush()` would not change anything.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Additionally, calling the script with `-u -i` doesn't work.

Comment: use either `python -u script.py` or `python -i` (no script file). There are *multiple* buffets!!! `p.stdin.flush()` is necessary (`bufsize=-1` by default) otherwise the child won't see you command (it will be inside the parent buffer)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian OK. `-u`, `-i` or `-u -i` don't work.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Anyway, I cannot make it work. I have added `p.stdin.flush` to the script, named test.py. It is called using `python -u test.py` in the console. And after inputing, e.g. `print('hello\n')`, the console gets stuck without any output.

Comment: I don't see the script name in your code. If there is no script; use `-i`, to enable the interactive mode. The code should look like: `Popen(['python', '-i'], ...)`. Also, it seems a newline is missing at the of the command.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Of course, you could not see the script name. The sample code is saved in a file, e.g. test.py. Then it is used as the argument of the python command.

Comment: Look at the code in your question, remove `-u`, add `-i`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Although I didn't edit the question, I have tested before the response. `Popen(['python', '-i'], ...)` doesn't work.

Comment: don't put the solution into the question. [Post it as your own answer instead](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). btw, the solution may fail if the input does not produce *exactly* one line e.g., if it returns 0, 2, 3, ... lines. You could fix it by passing `stderr=STDOUT` and reading until the prompt (`>>>`) occurs—though I don't see why do you want to run `python` as a subprocess from within `python`—it might be easier to use `multiprocessing` or if you need something more complex, see the architecture of something like `jupyter`, `celery`.

Comment: Just want to emphasize that the comment of @jfs really work for me!!!! (the usage of '-u' in Windows when calling the python command).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete working example that uses a subprocess interactively:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, DEVNULL

with Popen([sys.executable, '-i'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=DEVNULL,
           universal_newlines=True) as process:
    for i in range(10):
        print("{}**2".format(i), file=process.stdin, flush=True)
        square = process.stdout.readline()
        print(square, end='')
```

Here's another example: [how to run `[sys.executable, '-u', 'test.py']` interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33313566/4279).

Comment: As you commented, there are 3 problems in my code: 1. `python` should be started with `-i`; 2. `input` would strip the newline, so I have to manually add a newline when passing the command to `p.stdin`; 3. `p.stdin` must be flushed, or else `bufsize` should be set to `0`. Thank you!