# Print password prompt using Python's subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

If I run a terminal command from Python using `subprocess`, how do I print the password prompt?

I have a Python script that asks users to authenticate via **Kerberos**.  My program is basically this:

```
import subprocess

def kinit():
  kinit = "kinit -f"
  prompt = subprocess.check_output(kinit, shell=True)
  print prompt   ## echoes "Password for username@domain.com" AFTER pw input

if __name__=="__main__":
  kinit()
  doOtherStuff()
```

When this script is launched from the Terminal, the program waits for password input (which can be input via the command line), but it only displays the "Password for **username@domain.com**" prompt AFTER the user inputs their password.

Do you know how I can display the "Password for **username@domain.com**" before the Python script waits for them to input their password?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out you can't.  `subprocess` will not return output in the middle of a process, and the process will not complete until you input user input.

Answer (score 3):

It's an interactive thing, so you shouldn't be calling `check_output`.  That is usually used for subprocesses which will do some stuff and then terminate (without keyboard input required).

You can do what you want by making a `Popen` instance instead, and then interacting with it using `Popen.communicate`.  But it can be tricky to send input to the process stdin, and read lines from it's stdout correctly without deadlocking or buffering complications.

And there is a better way: [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) is great for this.  I recommend to ditch `subprocess` in favour of `pexpect` here.

Comment: This is the right answer.  Trying to make it work with subprocess is just going to lead to a great deal of frustration

Comment: Thanks for explaining (1) why `check_output` is less than ideal, and (2) that `Popen` and `pexpect` are more optimal solutions.  I will try these and see how they work.

Comment: @Logan: `pexpect` is preferrable due to [these reasons](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/FAQ.html#whynotpipe) but [it doesn't mean that `subprocess` can't be used in interactive case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23795689/4279)

Comment: You're absolutely right, it is entirely possible, but just more difficult