# read -p command in linux script is not displayed correctly by subprocess in python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, subprocess

I want to read output line by line

below is my bash code (meta.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello!"
read -p "Continue?(y/n)"
[ "$REPLY" == "y" ] || exit
echo "lol"
```

below is my subprocess code (test.py)

```
import subprocess
def create_subprocess(Command):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
       Command,
       shell=True,
       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
       stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
       bufsize=1
      )
   return proc
Command = "/root/Desktop/meta.sh"
proc = create_subprocess(Command)
while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if not line: break
    print line.strip()
```

now when i run "python test.py"
it shows

> hello!

now when I press y and press enter then it shows

> Continue?(y/n)
>
> lol

what ideally it should show is this

> hello!
>
> Continue?(y/n)

now when I press y and press enter then it should show

> lol

Comment: I think `readline` will read until a `\n` or `EOF` and the prompt line does not have either, so `readline` won't grab that first.  You could perhaps read char by char instead of trying to read the whole line

Comment: readline is not reading until a `\n` comes because as `read` comes it stops therefore `Continue?(y/n)` is displayed after i press 'y'. What else should I use that reads until a `\n` or `EOF` comes

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, the problem is that python's `readline` is waiting until it gets either an end of line or end of file, neither of which are produced by the `read -p` command (note that you type onto the same line, because there is not a line ending on that one).  That means your `readline` doesn't give you anything back until after `lol` is printed.  You can get around this by reading one char at a time though, like so:

```
while True:
    cur = proc.stdout.read(1)
    if(not cur):
        break
    sys.stdout.write(cur)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

though you'll have to `import sys` as well

This will display each character from `proc.stdout` as soon as it's read and not wait for newlines.

Comment: In general, if stdout is redirected to a pipe [the child process may use a block-buffering mode for its stdout](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279). `.read(1)` won't help if it is the case (the output is delayed in the internal buffer inside the child process). Though I would expect the shell to flush the prompt text and therefore `.read(1)` should be enough, [e.g, `read_until()` function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7897202/4279)