# Sending commands to terminal

Tags: python, linux, terminal, subprocess, xterm

I want to pipe some commands into a Xterm window which is opened by my python program.
I am on Linux and am using subprocess to comunicate with the terminal

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run("xterm -e python3 main.py",shell=True)
```

This opens a xterm window and runs the script , in the `main.py` file which i have called using the subprocess module contains this code :

```py
import time

while True:
    try:
        print("Me is running")
        time.sleep(5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Stoped:(")
        break
```

I want to give commands to the linux terminal.

So if I press `Ctrl+c` on the terminal , it should print *Stopped:(* on xterm.

Comment: Do you mean pass in commands from the parent process? Or manually interact with the subprocess?

Comment: yes i mean through the parent process. @tripleee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the subprocess in an `xterm` detaches you from its input and output file descriptors. The `run` call will block until the subprocess terminates, anyway.

A much better solution would be to run the subprocess as a direct child with `subprocess.Popen` or perhaps `pexpect`. Run the parent in a new `xterm` if you like; if it doesn't perform any I/O of its own, it will seem like the subprocess is solely in control.

The [Stack Overflow `subprocess` tag info page](/tags/subprocess/info) has several links to questions about how interact with a running subprocess.

Comment: What does I/O of its own mean , If I add an argument that if ctrl+c is pressed on the parent terminal all the text in the x-term has to written to file. would that be an I/O ??

Comment: If the parent script prints something to the terminal, you can't tell if it was printed by the parent or the child. Similarly, if the parent needs to read keyboard input, it can't (without cooperation from the child process).

Comment: So how do i actually do it ? I have been strugging for many hours with this. I saw the questions with tags of subprocess

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897202/subprocess-readline-hangs-waiting-for-eof seems to have several viable solutions. `pexpect` is probably overkill here, but could still be the simplest solution. If you insist on using `subprocess`, closing the parent process file descriptor to `stdin` might be necessary in order to let the child take over.

Answer (score -2):

i think its not possible to run commands on xterm or cmd using subprocess.
subprocess is used to execute the program directly. Not from a cmd or xterm. And also cmd or xterm doesn't takes any arguments

Comment: This is confused on several points. `xterm` does allow you to specify a command to run, and running `xterm` in a subprocess is perfectly fine (though I would generally recommend against it; many times, a better solution is to not have Python meddle with the user's GUI directly).